# How to add a hyperlink column in an UltraWebgrid that will redirect me to a popup window

Tags: infragistics, ultrawebgrid

I am pretty new to Infragistics controls and finding it hard to add a hyperlink column to the ultraweb grid. Can anyone help me out with this.

Currently, I am binding the data coming from the Database to the grid.
To this data I need to add a hyperlink column "View" that will redirect me to a popup.
I need to pass some values from this page to the popup.

Need pointers if this can be done on Javascript.
I am unable to get the code anywhere.

It would be really helpful if someone can help me out

Regards,
Sunitha

Answer (score 0):

If you know HTML it is actually pretty simple to do. On the Initialize RowLayout method of the UltraGrid and reference the cell you want the hyperlink to go into and within the text property place the link there using HTML and include parameters within the HTML to pass to the popup.

If you are using a fairly recent version of Infragistics, they have a Modal Popup window that you can use which is fairly easy to integrate and use, and with this you do not need a javascript popup. You can use the ClientSideEvent BeforeSelectChangeHandler to open the Modal popup and pass values into there by referring to other cells within the row.